# Unknown gap between elements in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a mystery space between the top **red** and **blue** bars.

What am I doing wrong? When I remove `main` the bar goes away. But the `footer` comes to the top?

I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9yrmafw/1/#

```css
.strip {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.bar {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.footer__body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="bar">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer__body">
        <p>© {{ copyright }} {{ now }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs due to [*`margin collapsing`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) of `h1` to the `bar` div - so you can either:

1. Reset margin to zero for the `h1`
2. Add a padding / border to `bar`

See demo below - I've added some padding to `bar`:

```css
.strip {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.bar {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.footer__body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="bar">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer__body">
        <p>© {{ copyright }} {{ now }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is *margin collapsing*, as pointed out in [@Kukkuz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41020033/3597276).

In addition to the two solutions mentioned in that answer – changing the `margin` or adding `border` / `padding` – both of which disable margin collapsing, there's a third: *make the parent a flex container*

Add this to your code:

```
.bar {
    display: flex;
}
```

In a ***flex formatting context***, margins do not collapse.

*From the spec:*

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` `display`
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents.
>
> This is the same as establishing a block formatting context, except
>   that flex layout is used instead of block layout.
>
> For example, floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the
>   flex container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its
>   contents.

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v9yrmafw/7/)

```css
.bar {
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex; /* NEW */
    justify-content: center; /* NEW */
}
.strip {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}  
.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.footer__body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="bar">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer__body">
        <p>© {{ copyright }} {{ now }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for h1

```css
.strip {
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    
  }
  
.bar {
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
   
  }
  
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  
}  

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.footer__body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="strip"></div>
    <div class="bar"><h1 style=" padding:0px;
    margin:0px;">Home</h1></div>
  </main>
  
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer__body">
        <p>© {{ copyright }} {{ now }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```